# Leaflet big GeoJson file Ajax filter best performance

Tags: javascript, ajax, filter, leaflet, geojson

I have four 2MB geoJson files with four Layer to load like

```
LayerBoon = L.geoJSON.ajax(URL, {pointToLayer:returnBoonMarker, filter:filtertext});
```

with a filter function and this button click function

```
$("#btnFindText").click(function(){
    SeachTXT = $("#txtFind").val();
    LayerSt.refresh();
    LayerPr.refresh();
    LayerHL.refresh();
    LayerBoon.refresh();
})
```

every Layer have to re-filter by clicking the button.

when filtering, is it possible not to reload the file each time, keep it in cache and filter it again?

Comment: You could use your favourite URL reader function to load the contents of the URL once into a variable and reference that variable in the `L.geoJSON` call. The `L.geoJSON.ajax` extension is just a shortcut.

Comment: @peeebeee
can you please show an example, i can't get it right.
i get a invalid GeoJSON object.

`async function addGeoJson(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = await response.json();
    //L.geoJson(data).addTo(mymap);   
    //console.log(data); 
}

var data1 = addGeoJson('\json_boon.json');

L.geoJson(data1).addTo(mymap);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use fetch:

```js
const api = 'json_boon.json';

async function fetchData(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, { cache: "force-cache" });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

fetchData(api)
  .then(data => {
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });
```

I added an additional parameter that forces the browser to cache files [cache: "force-cache"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache)

The first download is normal and the next ones are fetched from the disk cache, an expedient check the devtools.

**Update:**

```js
const geojsonOpts = {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return ...
  },
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return ...
  }
};

["one", "two", "three", "four"].map((json) => {
  fetchData(`./${json}.json`).then((data) => {
    L.geoJSON(data, geojsonOpts).addTo(map);
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question - (parsed) data isn't cached.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely true. Each served file should be cached, be it css, js or json. As you can see in the example, json is served from a relative address, so it has an impact on how the server behaves.
If there are problems with this, the appropriate parameter can be added to the fatch method [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache)

Comment: Seems like you have added the cache parameter onto the incorrect function. That being said, I am not sure what happens if the server responds with a `no-store` directive: does the browser comply with the fetch request or the response directive?

Comment: That's right I've already corrected it, it's late at my place;)
Well, that's about how the server is set up. I added this parameter only because it is not locally supporting file caching by "live server". Most servers have css, js, json, ico etc files set by default, or at least they should. If there is no caching then you can change it in ..htaccess by adding `ExpiresByType application/json" access plus 1 month"`
I did not test this solution with fetch and cache because all the servers I worked on had cach enabled, and if not, I set it up using `.htaccess`

Comment: Another solution, if it is not possible to interfere with the server, is to insert json into `indexedDB` and download them dynamically from the database. The only problem with indexedDB is slow data insertion, unfortunately in Chrome;). Of course, here we are talking about four files of 2MB so it shouldn't be a problem. I am currently working on inserting 300k. (~ 25MB) coordinates and showing only those markers that will be in the map.getBounds()
I will try my luck with the Dexie.js library which improves my work with indexedDB

Comment: Thx  `force-cache` looking great. Now, how can i refilter with the data cashe? Put it in the function `fetchData(api)` ?

Comment: In the same way as you did with the L.geosjon.ajax library. I supplemented the example with the solution with files. The idea in this featch is that the file is downloaded only once, and each refresh of the downloaded file is done locally. It's best to create a working prototype and place it on codepen.io, codesandbox.io or another website.

Comment: is it right: all layer cluster filters and so on have to be inside the fetch? thx for your time